# C++ Linux: OpenPrinter equivalent

Tags: c++, linux, qt, printing

I'm using Qt. I need to write some text to my printer directly. On windows I can do this using winapi OpenPrinter and WritePrinter, but I need this code to run on linux but I can't find this function OpenPrinter on linux. I know I can write directly to linux /dev/usb/lpX file like this:

```
char *dev = "/dev/usb/lp0";
int printerfile = open(dev, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY) ;
if (printerfile < 0)
{
        cout << "Failed to open "<<dev;
        exit(-1);
}
string str = "test 12345";
write(printerfile,str.c_str(),str.length());
```

but this need device path like /dev/usb/lp0 and I can only get Printer name from Qt like EPSON LX-300+.

Comment: You don't want to directly open a printer. There isn't necessarily one attached to the machine. Lots of printers are networked. Why not use QPrinter like a good law-abiding Qt citizen, and stop worrying about OS-specific stuff? Failing that, use CUPS interface (basically, run `lp`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397683/how-to-print-text-file-to-printer-in-qt

Comment: @n.m. I have tried that but  this QPrinter is buggy on printer dot matrix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310797/qt-printing-on-printer-dot-matrix

Comment: @SimonKraemer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310797/qt-printing-on-printer-dot-matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can try to learn more about yours Linux OS attached printer by command:

```
[udevadm info -q all -n /dev/usb/lp0]
```

Output is something like bellow:

```
-------------
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-
1.2:1.0/usbmisc/lp0
N: usb/lp0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/usb/lp0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-
1.2:1.0/usbmisc/lp0
E: MAJOR=180
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=usbmisc
E: UDEV_LOG=3
-------------
```